nlog INSIDE of a Soap Api
I want to log information INSIDE of a soap api, using NLOG.  But all I am finding is how to setup NLOG so the external website makes a call to the api and it uses NLOG to log the data.  I need to see what is going on INSIDE my api so I can debug it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I cant even get NLOGs internal logging to work.  Here is my nlog.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="nlog-internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="Trace">
</nlog>

as far I understand, this alone should at least create an internal log file for NLOG itself.  I can add the targets and rules after I get this part working.  Note: I did add nlog to the project. NLOG 5.3.2

Turns out in my web config, I was calling the API on the server and not the one in visual studio. So no nlog code was being called.  (Silly me).
